# Linux, piping together apt-get update and apt-get upgrade

Tags: linux, django, ubuntu, fabric

I am trying my hand at deploying a small django app I have created on a remote server using fabric. As this is fresh server and after googling, I observed that I had to run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` commands to update the system packages.

The command I provided using fabric api is

```
run('apt-get update && apt-get upgrade')
```

I get

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

How do I execute this commands so that I do not face this error

Comment: Try maybe run sudo() instead of run() ?

Comment: Tried, problem persists

Comment: Run `sudo ps aux | grep 'apt-get' | grep -v grep` to check if there is another process using the `apt-get` command?

Comment: Its been my experience that if you cant do it with fabric that means you cant do it in regular ssh, i suggest you look at the user you're using to run this. I always connect with a user that has sudo access, that way i can do what ever low level provisioning i need to. Then when i need to start actually copying code/ configuring i do `with settings(user='<very limited user here>'), cd('<path that you already created with root and gave rights to limited user here>'): run(...)` and ta-da! (from fabric.api import run, settings, cd)

Comment: User was root. Got it done later, but manually coz aptitude was taking time configuring newly downloaded kernels and had a lock on dpkg. Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

In this case you just have to remove the lock:

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock

and then try to execute the command

Let me know if its helps if not then follow the following:

sudo su
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock 
apt-get update

and then execute the command
update and upgrade command on single line and if its works then go for api

Comment: On your suggestion I tried the following but still the problem exists
    print('--------UPDATE-------')
    run('echo {0} | sudo -S apt-get -y update'.format(password))
    print('--------UPGRADE-------')
    sudo('rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock')
    run('echo {0} | sudo -S apt-get -y upgrade'.format(password))

Answer (score 0):

It means another process is already running an apt-get command.
Close your other terminal windows, and perhaps any GUI's you have open that use apt-get.

Comment: No GUI's on the remote server my script executes apt-get update then apt-get upgrade back to back

Comment: Executing those two command is no problem. But there is still a process using apt-get, which has it locked. Kill any processes, remove the lock manually. If you want a simple solution you might want to restart te server.

Comment: See the server is 14.04, when I run apt-get update manually on the server linux kernel starts updating. Now can it be a case that just because the whole update the kernel process hasn't completed and fabric issues upgrade command, the lock on dpkg exists? It sounds weird but may be